# insert images sequentially in Derby Blob column

Tags: java, image, blob, inputstream, derby

what I need is :

```
for(int x=0; x< multipleImagesListCount; x++){

    inputStream = multipleImagesList.get(x);

    //here I need a way  tells the setBlob() to insert the new added image after whatever
    // saved data in the column….then the loop will keep add every new image the same way 

    ps.setBlob(paramInt , inputStream);
    ps.execut...
    ...
}
```

more details on the issue :

Derby blob column stores images, using preparedstatement.setBlob(parameter,inputStream)….which works fine adding each image BUT deleting whatever saved data in the column !!

How to adds multiple images   :

1- Sequentially one after the other .

2- The first new added image should come in position after the last already saved image( in case there are saved ones)

a- Adding the multiple images to a list and looping through them not solve the issue of deleting whatever saved data in the column,

b- Using blob.setBinaryStream(pos) where pos is the blob.length() ...this will gives you outputStream but you won’t be able to use …

Comment: Have you tried working through the blobs tutorial in the Java JDBC tutorial series? This will teach you a lot about how to work with blobs and JDBC: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html

Comment: @Ravi...thanks for the link, I'm saving the blobs directly in the DB through fileChooser without use of  intermediate File ( that sits in the fileSystem )in the link they use  String fileName ,with fileName things are easy ...

Comment: It's a stand alone Derby DB..